# Python 3 Save Buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, pickle

I have a button that can create another buttons, but when I close the program, the buttons I just created disappear.

I know how to save things in a file using pickle, but how should I write the code so that it saves the buttons and creates them again when I open the program.

code:

```
def CreateButton():
    global name,clicked,started
    started=True
    name = str(input("Write a Student Name..."))
    print('variable changed...')
    clicked=True

def update():
    global MainWindow,changed,clicked,name
    #global clicked
    if clicked and started:
        #name = input("Write a Student Name: ")
        button_new=needed_but(MainWindow=MainWindow,color="#E6E6E6",text=name)
        clicked=False
        buttonred=False
    MainWindow.after(1*1000,update)

class needed_but:
    def __init__(self,MainWindow,color,text):
        console = Button(MainWindow, text=text,bg=color, command=self.changecolor)
        console.pack()
        self.instance=console

    def changecolor(self):
        buttonred,buttongreen,buttonblue=get_color()
        global clicked,misses_dict
        #clicked=True
        #global buttoncolor
        if buttonred == True:
            self.instance.configure(bg = "#ff0000")
            dun = self.instance.cget('text')
            print(dun)
            if dun in misses_dict:
                misses_dict[('%s' %(dun))] += 1
            else:
                misses_dict[('%s' %(dun))] = 1
            pickle.dump(dictionary, open("%s\SI\SIA.dat" %(path), 'wb'))
            print(misses_dict)
            buttonred = False
        elif buttongreen == True:
            self.instance.configure(bg = "#00ff00")
        elif buttonblue == True:
            self.instance.configure(bg = "#2e9afe")
```

Comment: You can't pickle actual buttons, but you can pickle all the information you used to create the buttons (e.g., a list of (color, text) pairs).Then, at the end of setting up your interface, read that pickle file if present, and create a button for each entry in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how should I write the code so that it saves the buttons and creates them again when I open the program.

You can't. The objects are actually objects within an embedded tcl interpreter. There's no way to save the state of the interpreter.

You'll have to write code to save all of the information about the widgets in some sort of format where you can read it back and recreate the widgets.

Comment: @TavoGamer: you can call the `configure` method on any widget to get a list of its configured option values.